# Selecting elasticsearch memory storage

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to know which setting I have to set for selecting an onheap or offheap memory index. It seems that `index.store.type=memory` stores index data offheap, but I need to store my data onheap.

I looked at the documentation and wasn't able to find this setting.

Thanks,

Joan.

Comment: Can you explain why you would absolutely need to store your index on the heap? Isn't the main memory space good enough?

Comment: I need the maximum performance, it doesn't matter persistence in my case. Trying onheap/offheap with IMDGs there is a significant performance difference between onheap and offheap (my app is a financial app where every millisecond counts). Furthermore GC is not a problem for us becuase we are using Zing jvm.

Comment: Anyways I will try both onheap/offheap indexes, but this will be impossible if I don't know how to setup an onheap/offheap index. Thanks.